# Add special Character to All Wordpress Titles

Tags: php, wordpress, title, page-title

Is there a way to force a "#" sign to automatically be added to the beginning of all wordpress post titles?

I know you can force it to be capitalized or lowercase, etc.. but can you add a special character or word to the beginning of them all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think amanda was talking about all titles, not online browser's title..

You could use this function as a plugin, or in your functions.php page:

```
add_filter('the_title', function($title) { return '#'. $title;})
```

Comment: Perfect, I was talking about all titles not the browsers title. I will try and plug this in and see if I can get it working!

Comment: Have you tried it? Don't forget do mark as answer if it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

In your template folder search for the `header.php` file and then inside this file search for the `<title>` tag.

Now add a `#` right after the `<title>` and it will occur on all pages.